# React: onClick vs OnKeyDown

Tags: reactjs

I'm fairly new to React coding, but looking to understand some curious behaviour in code I've inherited. The following snippet drives the closure of a pane/panel in an application I'm seeking to understand, but operates differently when invoked via a mouse click vs 'Enter key'.

```
const closeButton = (onClose) => (
  <div
    data-testid="abstract-pane-close-button"
    className="abstract-pane-component abstract-pane-close-button"
    onClick={onClose}
    aria-label="Close"
    type="button"
    role="button"
    tabIndex={0}
    onKeyDown={({ key }) => {
      if (key === keys.ENTER.key) {
        onClose();
      }
    }}
  >
    <CloseIcon />
  </div>
);
```

Both invoke the onClose function, which in turn, sets a piece of state data to a null object. The appearance of the pane/panel is conditional on this state data being non-null, hence invoking onClose function(and setting the state data to null) should make it disappear. This works fine when invoked via onClick, but doesn't via onKeyDown. I'm perplexed!

A notable difference is the use of parentheses when invoking via the ENTER key, but not via the click event, but I'm struggling to understand whether this is significant or not? Can anyone offer an insight...or tell me I'm off into an irrelevant rabbit hole?!

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**

`keys` is an object that's imported. Its structure is shown below:

```
export const keys = { 
  ENTER: { 
    key: 'Enter', 
    keyCode: 13 
  }, 
  ESCAPE: { 
    key: 'Escape', 
    keyCode: 27 
  }, 
  ESCAPE_IE_EDGE: { 
    key: 'Esc', 
    keyCode: 27 
  }, 
  ... ... 
}
```

Comment: are you sure 'key === keys.ENTER.key'? Can't see what the 'keys' object is

Comment: Would be great if you could share a minimal, reproducible example to allow others to test the problem.

Comment: _"A notable difference is the use of parentheses when invoking via the ENTER key, but not via the click event"_ - you need to provide a function that will be called when that event is triggered. With `onClick`, that function is `onClose` whereas in the case of `onKeyDown`, that function is the anonymous function and in the body of that anonymous function, you call `onClose`.

Comment: @BenClayton : Thanks Ben, keys is an object that's imported...it looks like this...

export const keys = {
  ENTER: { key: 'Enter', keyCode: 13 },
  ESCAPE: { key: 'Escape', keyCode: 27 },
  ESCAPE_IE_EDGE: { key: 'Esc', keyCode: 27 },
...
...
};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
onKeyDown={(e) => {
 if (e.code === "Enter") {
   e.preventDefault();
   onClose();
 }
}}
```

Comment: Thanks @Akask this 100% solved the immediate problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `onKeyDown` is only applicable for focused and interactive elements. To make it useful for your case, you should add a global event `keydown` within `useEffect` in your component (remember to clean the global event up too).

```js
const keys = { 
  ENTER: { 
key: 'Enter', 
keyCode: 13 
  },
}
 
const CloseButton = ({onClose}) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
     const handleKeyDown = ({ key }) => {
      if (key === keys.ENTER.key) {
        onClose();
      }
     }
     //add a global event for `keydown`
     window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)
    //clean up after component unmounted
    return () => window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)
  }, [])

  return <div
    data-testid="abstract-pane-close-button"
    className="abstract-pane-component abstract-pane-close-button"
    onClick={onClose}
    aria-label="Close"
    type="button"
    role="button"
  >
    Button
  </div>
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <CloseButton onClose={() => alert('testing')}/>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```